# Add HATEAOS links to ASP .NET REST Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I'm using the ASP.Net Web API to build a RESTful Service. I'm struggling to find a clean way to add HATEAOS links into the json returned to my clients.

For example I have

```
public class LongRequest
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int Progress {get;set;}
}

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(LongRequest request)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, request);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { Id  = request.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

I want my returned json to include a Cancel and Self link in the json that looks like

'

```
{
"LongRequest":{
"Id":"32",
"Progress":"33",
"link":{
         "rel":"self",
         "href":"/LongRequest/32"
      },
"link":{
         "rel":"cancel",
         "href":"/LongRequest/32"
      },
}
}
```

'
What I've done right now is created a link class.

```
 public class Link
 {
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
 }
```

and modified LongRequest to be

```
public class LongRequest
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Progress {get;set;}
    public Link self
    {
        get{
            return new Link(){href="/Status/"+Id,method="GET"};
        }
     }
     public Link cancel
     {
        get{
            return new Link() { href = "/Status/" + Id, method = "DELETE" };
        }
     }
}
```

Which results in json that looks like

```
{
   "Id":0,
   "Progress":1,
   "self":{"method":"GET","href":"/Status/0"},
   "cancel":{"method":"DELETE","href":"/Status/0"}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include links in a standardized way then take a look at some of the hypermedia enabled formats:

- Mason: https://github.com/JornWildt/Mason
- HAL: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-07
- Siren: https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren
- Collection+JSON: http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/
- JSON API: http://jsonapi.org/
- Hydra: http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/